# Angular 9 does not use any component styles (IVY disabled)

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-builder, angular9

I am currently trying to get a project running with **Angular 9 RC6**. Unfortunately it is not able to compile with Angular Ivy, probably because of one of the dependencies. So I have to disable Ivy. It uses Angular Material and all the projects style files are `.scss` files. Building and serving runs successfully.

But when I serve (or build and serve) the website, none of the component related styles are applied. Although it uses the Angular Material styles properly.

The project was initiated with `create-nx-workspace` from Nrwl/Nx. In the **angular.json** file there is the schematic

```json
"projects": {
  "myProject": {
    "projectType": "application",
    "schematics": {
      "@nrwl/angular:component": {
        "style": "scss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the builder is `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` for building or `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server` for serving.

Here are my Angular dependencies (after the empty line devDependencies):

```json
"@angular/animations": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/common": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/fire": "^5.3.0-rc.2",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/material": "^9.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/service-worker": "^9.0.0-rc.6",

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.6",
"@angular/cli": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-rc.6",
```

Do you have any idea how I am able to debug this issue? Please let me know if information is missing.

Cheers and Thanks!

Comment: If you inspect some random elements in the built site (not the served one) do you actually see the class(es) name(s) on those elements? And, if yes, in the right part, in any computed style?

Comment: The classes are applied properly. But the `element.style {}` is empty when it shouldn't. But for external libraries I am seeing a lot of `.mat-body, .mat-drawer-container` which contain styles.

Comment: But the styles from `styles.scss` at the project source root, which also is mentioned in the `styles` array of the **angular.json**, are applied correctly.

Comment: have you found any solution?